# GridView RowDataBound event handler does not find GridView cells content

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have the following `GridView`, which has as `DataSource` a `List<T>`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDownloads" UseAccessibleHeader="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" 
              CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="productid">
             <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No licenses found 
             </EmptyDataTemplate>
             <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" >
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%# Eval("ProductId")%>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%# Eval("ProductName")%>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock Code">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <%# Eval("StockCode")%>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Which renders correctly and with the proper values.

Now, I would like to modify on the fly the field **StockCode** and in order to do so I have in my code behind:

```
Sub gvDownloads_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDownlads.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

         e.Row.Cells(2).Text = StockCodeConverter.Convert(e.Row.Cells(2).Text)

    End If
End Sub
```

But the data cells corresponding to **StockCode** are empty. Now I tried to debug and for some reason the code finds just the value of the header row. The values of the other rows are `string.Empty` or &nsbp. Might it depend on the List as DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASP.NET controls instead, for example [`Labels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx):

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     Dim lblStockCode = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblStockCode"), Label)
    lblStockCode.Text = StockCodeConverter.Convert(lblStockCode.Text)
End If
```

on aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock Code">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Id="LblStockCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StockCode") %>'></asp:label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can even omit the `Eval` on aspx and set the `Text` property completely in codebehind:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
     Dim lblStockCode = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblStockCode"), Label)
    lblStockCode.Text = StockCodeConverter.Convert(row["StockCode"].ToString)
End If
```

**Edit**: If you want to stay with your text and also with the `TemplateField` you could cast the first control in the cell which is a autogenerated [`DataBoundLiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databoundliteralcontrol.aspx) when there's only text and use it's `Text` property.

```
Dim StockCode = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).Controls(0), DataBoundLiteralControl).Text
```

But that makes your code less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try your solution! Anyway may you explain me why it does not find the values? The DataBind happens later?

Comment: @CiccioMiami: Because a `TemplateField`contains controls that you can access via their ID's. If you don't want to use it you can use a `BoundField`, then the `Text` property of the cell would not be empty.

Comment: I didn't know that, the web is full of examples about rowdatabound but none of them in the scope of this situation! Thanks for the explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think in GridView RowDataBound Event as the Binding is still in process you are not getting any Value...I would suggest you to use "DataRowView"

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
e.Row.Cells(2).Text = drv["StockCode"].ToString();
```